Overlapping buttons and text entry box
Currently, I am doing a project trying to make a weather recommendation app. My current dilemma is that  when I execute the app the window pops up as intended but, when I try to insert a reset button to delete the entries a user inputs it overlaps the convert button. I've been using the grid()function instead of the pack(). I am also having an issue with pressing the previous and next buttons as the entry box moves along with it when pressed. I want the entry box and in the future the result box to only be on page 2 instead of every page.
I have attempted to solve the issue by using columns and rows, as well as the sticky option, but unfortunately, I was not able to find a solution. My objective is to have the reset button and convert button placed next to each other. As well as the entry box for the user inputted temperature to only remain on page 2 along with the result label I plan on making.
import tkinter as tk

class Myapp(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, root):

    
        self.current_page_index = 0
        self.pages = [self.page1, self.page2, ]#self.page3]

        self.color1 = '#95d6ea'
        self.color2 = '#62a1c7'
        self.color3 = 'White'

        super().__init__(
            root,
            bg = self.color1
        )

        self.main_page = self

        self.main_page.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand =  True)
        self.main_page.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.main_page.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.load_main_widgets()

    #Defines the formula to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit
    def Celsius_to_Fahrenheit(Celsius):
        return (1.8) * Celsius + 32
    
    #Defines the formula to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
    def Fahrenheit_to_Celsius(Fahrenheit):
        return (0.55) * (Fahrenheit - 32)
    #The float class is used so the user is able to input decimial numbers, an uses the .2f so the output is rounded up two decimal places.  
    #def convert_temperature():
        try:
            temperature = float(entry.get())
            if temperature_type.get() == "Celsius":
                result = Celsius_to_Fahrenheit(temperature)
                result_label.config(text =f"{temperature} Celsius is {result:.2f} Fahrenehit")
            else:
                result = Fahrenheit_to_Celsius(temperature)
                result_label.config(text = f"{temperature} Fahrenheit is {result:.2f} Celsius")
        except ValueError:
            result_label.config(text = "Invalid User input. Please enter a valid number.")
    
    def load_main_widgets(self):
        self.create_page_container()
        self.create_pager()
        self.pages[self.current_page_index]()
       
        
    def clear_frame(self, frame):
        for child in frame.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()

    def create_page_container(self):
        
        self.page_container = tk.Frame(
        self.main_page,
        background = self.color1
        )

        self.page_container.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.page_container.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.page_container.rowconfigure(1, weight = 1)

        self.page_container.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)

    def create_pager(self):
        
        self.pager = tk.Frame(
            self.main_page,
            background = self.color1,
            height = 125,
            width = 400,
        )

        self.pager.columnconfigure(1, weight = 1)
        self.pager.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        self.pager.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = tk.NS)
        self.pager.grid_propagate(0)


        def change_page(button):
            self.clear_frame(self.page_container)

            match button:
                case "Previous":
                    self.current_page_index -= 1
                    self.pages[self.current_page_index]()
                case "Next":
                    self.current_page_index += 1
                    self.pages[self.current_page_index]()

            if self.current_page_index == 0:
                previous_button.config(state =tk.DISABLED)
            else:
                previous_button.config(state = tk.ACTIVE) 
            if self.current_page_index == len(self.pages) - 1:
                next_button.config(state =tk.DISABLED)  
            else:
                next_button.config(state =tk.ACTIVE)
            
            self.page_number["text"] = f'{self.current_page_index + 1}/{len(self.pages)}'

        previous_button = tk.Button(
            self.pager,
            background = self.color2,
            foreground = self.color3,
            activebackground = self.color2,
            activeforeground = self.color3,
            disabledforeground = '#3B3A56',
            highlightthickness = 0,
            width = 7,
            relief = tk.FLAT,
            font = ("Comic Sans", 10),
            text = "Previous",
            state = tk.DISABLED,
            command = lambda button = "Previous" :change_page(button)
        )

        previous_button.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = tk.SW)

        self.page_number = tk.Label(
            self.pager,
            background = self.color1,
            foreground = self.color3, 
            font = ("Comic Sans", 10),
            text = f'{self.current_page_index + 1}/{len(self.pages)}'
        )

        self.page_number.grid(column = 1, row = 0)


        next_button = tk.Button(
            self.pager,
            background = self.color2,
            foreground = self.color3,
            activebackground = self.color2,
            activeforeground = self.color3,
            disabledforeground = '#3B3A56',
            highlightthickness = 0,
            width = 7,
            relief = tk.FLAT,
            font = ("Comic Sans", 10),
            text = "Next",
            command = lambda button = "Next" :change_page(button)
        )

        next_button.grid(column = 2, row = 0, sticky = tk.SE)

    def page1(self):

        title = tk.Label(
            self.page_container,
            background = self.color1, 
            foreground = self.color3,
            height = 2,
            font = ("Comic Sans", 25),
            text = "Welcome!"
        )
        title.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

        text = ("Hello, and welcome to my weather recommendation app! "
                "To continue to the application please click next or click to exit window.")

        content = tk.Label(
            self.page_container,
            background = self.color2,
            foreground = self.color3,
            justify = tk.LEFT,
            anchor = tk.N,
            pady = 20,
            font = ("Comic Sans", 22),
            text = text, 
            wraplength= 600
        )

        content.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = tk.NSEW)

    def page2(self):

        title = tk.Label(
            self.page_container,
            background = self.color1, 
            foreground = self.color3,
            height = 2,
            font = ("Comic Sans", 20),
            text = "Enter Outside Temperature "
        )
        title.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

        #Allows the user to input an integer for the temperature
        entry_Label = tk.Entry(self, width = 10)
        entry_Label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        #Defines the function that allows user to reset the entry
        #def clearFunc():
            #entry.delete(0,"end")

        #Reset button allows user to delete inputted integers 
        #reset_button = tk.Button(text = "Reset", command = clearFunc)
        #reset_button.grid(row = 0, column = 3)

        #Convert buttons allows the user to convert temperatures from Celsius to Fahrenheit and vice    versa
        convert_button = tk.Button(self, text = "Convert")
        convert_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        #Result label output
        result_label = tk.Label(self, text ="")
        result_label.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        content = tk.Label(
            self.page_container,
            background = self.color2,
            foreground = self.color3,
            justify = tk.LEFT,
            anchor = tk.N,
            pady = 20,
            font = ("Comic Sans", 10),
            wraplength= 600
        )

        content.grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = tk.NSEW)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Dave's Weather Recommendation app")
root.geometry('775x520')
root.resizable(width = False, height = False)
my_app_instance = Myapp(root)
root.mainloop()


There is no reset button shown when running your code.  It is better to provide a [mre].

@acw1668.   There is reset button. Comment out line 199 and  line 200 replace entry with entry_Label. And in Line 36, comment in. And in  line 204  replace grid  with pack.

I recommend you use the tab widget or close the first window and make a second window to reset the first page
